# Setting CSV content-type, difference between octet-stream and text/csv

Tags: csv, http, mime-types

What is the difference on using content type of `application/octet-stream` instead of `text/csv` for setting content type for a csv file, it seems they both produce the same result. Which method is preffered more? Just curious.

Comment: Perhaps see also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12539058/is-there-a-default-mime-type/12560996#12560996

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Some browsers, particularly IE, completely ignore the content type header, and open the response in an application according to the file extension. In those browsers, it probably doesn't matter.

However, text/csv is the preferred content type, and should work properly with all browsers. "application/octet-stream" is very generic, and does not give any hint as to what type of application should be used to open the result.

If you were returning an MS Excel file, for instance, you would use application/vnd.ms-excel to be more specific. Since CSV is not tied to one particular application, text/csv is preferred.

Answer (score 1):

`RFC` has an official document for `text/csv` from 2014 year.

For CSV file officially preferred to use `text/csv`.

https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7111.html

https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4180.html

https://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/text/csv

Answer (score -1):

There is no official RFC document for CSV files, but they are a flat text file, so the best MIME type to use would be `text/plain`.

There are OS specific MIME implementations for CSV files. For example, Microsoft use `application/vnd.ms-excel`.

For other MIME types, refer to this site: http://webdesign.about.com/od/multimedia/a/mime-types-by-content-type.htm

Comment: Any browser that actually tries to honor "text/plain" ContentType header would most likely offer to open the result in a text editor, rather than a spreadsheet. This is probably not what most users would expect. "text/csv", while unofficial, is widely supported, and so is probably a better choice.