# Why does file uploaded to S3 have content type application/octet-stream unless I name the file .html?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, s3cmd

Even though I set content type to text/html it ends up as application/octet-stream on S3.

```
ByteArrayInputStream contentsAsStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(contentAsBytes);
ObjectMetadata md = new ObjectMetadata();
md.setContentLength(contentAsBytes.length);
md.setContentType("text/html");
s3.putObject(new PutObjectRequest(ARTIST_BUCKET_NAME, artistId, contentsAsStream, md));
```

If however I name the file so that it ends up with .html

```
s3.putObject(new PutObjectRequest(ARTIST_BUCKET_NAME, artistId + ".html", contentsAsStream, md));
```

then it works.

Is my md object just being ignored? How can I get round this programmatically as over time I need to upload thousands of files so cannot just go into S3 UI and manually fix the contentType.

Comment: How do you check content type? In AWS S3 UI or by API? If by API can you paste the code.

Do you use latest version of AWS SDK? If so can you try with one.

Comment: I check content type by opening looking at the contentype in a webbrowser within S3 console

Comment: Im using aws version 1.9.6 which I believed to be the latest

Answer (score 15):

You must be doing something else in your code. I just tried your code example using the 1.9.6 S3 SDK and the file gets the "text/html" content type.

Here's the exact (Groovy) code:

```
class S3Test {
    static void main(String[] args) {

        def s3 = new AmazonS3Client()

        def random = new Random()
        def bucketName = "raniz-playground"
        def keyName = "content-type-test"

        byte[] contentAsBytes = new byte[1024]
        random.nextBytes(contentAsBytes)

        ByteArrayInputStream contentsAsStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(contentAsBytes);
        ObjectMetadata md = new ObjectMetadata();
        md.setContentLength(contentAsBytes.length);
        md.setContentType("text/html");
        s3.putObject(new PutObjectRequest(bucketName, keyName, contentsAsStream, md))

        def object = s3.getObject(bucketName, keyName)
        println(object.objectMetadata.contentType)
        object.close()
    }
}
```

The program prints

> text/html

And the S3 metadata says the same:

[image: S3 properties view]

Here are the communication sent over the net (courtesy of Apache HTTP Commons debug logging):

```
>> PUT /content-type-test HTTP/1.1
>> Host: raniz-playground.s3.amazonaws.com
>> Authorization: AWS <nope>
>> User-Agent: aws-sdk-java/1.9.6 Linux/3.2.0-84-generic Java_HotSpot(TM)_64-Bit_Server_VM/25.45-b02/1.8.0_45
>> Date: Fri, 12 Jun 2015 02:11:16 GMT
>> Content-Type: text/html
>> Content-Length: 1024
>> Connection: Keep-Alive
>> Expect: 100-continue
<< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
<< x-amz-id-2: mOsmhYGkW+SxipF6S2+CnmiqOhwJ62WfWUkmZk4zU3rzkWCEH9P/bT1hUz27apmO
<< x-amz-request-id: 8706AE3BE8597644
<< Date: Fri, 12 Jun 2015 02:11:23 GMT
<< ETag: "6c53debeb28f1d12f7ad388b27c9036d"
<< Content-Length: 0
<< Server: AmazonS3

>> GET /content-type-test HTTP/1.1
>> Host: raniz-playground.s3.amazonaws.com
>> Authorization: AWS <nope>
>> User-Agent: aws-sdk-java/1.9.6 Linux/3.2.0-84-generic Java_HotSpot(TM)_64-Bit_Server_VM/25.45-b02/1.8.0_45
>> Date: Fri, 12 Jun 2015 02:11:23 GMT
>> Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8
>> Connection: Keep-Alive
<< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
<< x-amz-id-2: 9U1CQ8yIYBKYyadKi4syaAsr+7BV76Q+5UAGj2w1zDiPC2qZN0NzUCQNv6pWGu7n
<< x-amz-request-id: 6777433366DB6436
<< Date: Fri, 12 Jun 2015 02:11:24 GMT
<< Last-Modified: Fri, 12 Jun 2015 02:11:23 GMT
<< ETag: "6c53debeb28f1d12f7ad388b27c9036d"
<< Accept-Ranges: bytes
<< Content-Type: text/html
<< Content-Length: 1024
<< Server: AmazonS3
```

And this is also the behaviour that looking at the [source code](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-java/blob/1.9.6/aws-java-sdk-s3/src/main/java/com/amazonaws/services/s3/AmazonS3Client.java#L1328) shows us - if you set the content type the SDK won't override it.

Comment: This doesn't explain why it's reset to "application/octet-stream" when explicitly set to "text/html". :P

Comment: No, but it *proves* that it doesn't =)

Answer (score 8):

Because you have to set content type at the end **just before sending, using the putObject method**;

```
        ObjectMetadata md = new ObjectMetadata();

        InputStream myInputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(bFile); 
        md.setContentLength(bFile.length);
        md.setContentType("text/html");
        md.setContentEncoding("UTF-8");

        s3client.putObject(new PutObjectRequest(bucketName, keyName, myInputStream, md));
```

And after upload, content type is set as "**text/html**"

[image]

Here is a working dummy code, check that out, I've just tried and it's working;

```
public class TestAWS {

    //TEST
    private static String bucketName = "whateverBucket";

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        BasicAWSCredentials awsCreds = new BasicAWSCredentials("whatever", "whatever");

        AmazonS3 s3client = new AmazonS3Client(awsCreds);
        try
        {
            String uploadFileName = "D:\\try.txt";
            String keyName = "newFile.txt";

            System.out.println("Uploading a new object to S3 from a file\n");
            File file = new File(uploadFileName);

            //bFile will be the placeholder of file bytes
            byte[] bFile = new byte[(int) file.length()];
            FileInputStream fileInputStream=null;

            //convert file into array of bytes  
            fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(file);
            fileInputStream.read(bFile);
            fileInputStream.close();

            ObjectMetadata md = new ObjectMetadata();

            InputStream myInputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(bFile); 
            md.setContentLength(bFile.length);
            md.setContentType("text/html");
            md.setContentEncoding("UTF-8");

            s3client.putObject(new PutObjectRequest(bucketName, keyName, myInputStream, md));
        } catch (AmazonServiceException ase)
        {
            System.out.println("Caught an AmazonServiceException, which "
                    + "means your request made it "
                    + "to Amazon S3, but was rejected with an error response"
                    + " for some reason.");
            System.out.println("Error Message:    " + ase.getMessage());
            System.out.println("HTTP Status Code: " + ase.getStatusCode());
            System.out.println("AWS Error Code:   " + ase.getErrorCode());
            System.out.println("Error Type:       " + ase.getErrorType());
            System.out.println("Request ID:       " + ase.getRequestId());
        } catch (AmazonClientException ace)
        {
            System.out.println("Caught an AmazonClientException, which "
                    + "means the client encountered "
                    + "an internal error while trying to "
                    + "communicate with S3, "
                    + "such as not being able to access the network.");
            System.out.println("Error Message: " + ace.getMessage());
        }

    }

}
```

Hope that it helps.

Answer (score 3):

[It seems](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/s3/model/ObjectMetadata.html) that

> When uploading files, the AWS S3 Java client will attempt to determine
>   the correct content type if one hasn't been set yet. Users are
>   responsible for ensuring a suitable content type is set when uploading
>   streams. If no content type is provided and cannot be determined by
>   the filename, the default content type, "application/octet-stream",
>   will be used.

Giving the file a .html extension provides a way to set the correct type.

According to the examples I've been looking at, the code you show *should* be doing what you want to do. :/

Comment: This doesn't explain why it's reset to "application/octet-stream" when explicitly set to "text/html".

Comment: Because that content type seems to be not properly set, aws find the most appropriote. But if you set content type just before using the putObject method, content type will be set. You can check out my answer.

Answer (score 2):

I could fix this issue easily by commandline, I faced similar issue while uploading html files through `aws commandline` even though the file name had correct extension.

As mentioned in earlier comments, adding `--content-type` param fixes the issue.
Executing below command and refreshing page returned octet stream.

```
aws s3api put-object --bucket [BUCKETNAME] --body index.html  --key index.html     --profile [PROFILE] --acl public-read
```

Fix: add `--content type text/html`

```
aws s3api put-object --bucket [BUCKETNAME] --body index.html  --key index.html  --profile [PROFILE] --acl public-read --content-type text/html
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the [AWS SDK for Java 2.x](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/latest/developer-guide/home.html), it is possible to add the content type within the builder pattern.

For example, uploading a Base64-encoded image as a JPEG object to S3 (assuming you have already instantiated an S3 client):

```java
byte[] stringAsByteArray = java.util.Base64.getDecoder().decode(base64EncodedString);

s3Client.putObject(
        PutObjectRequest.builder().bucket("my-bucket").key("my-key").contentType("image/jpg").build(),
        RequestBody.fromBytes(stringAsByteArray)
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you have any Override on the default mime content on your S3 account? Look at this link to see how to check it: [How to override default Content Types](http://s3browser.com/features-content-mime-types-editor.php).

Anyway, it looks like your S3 client fails to determine the correct mime-type by the content of the file, so it relies on the extension. octet-stream is the widely used default content mime type when a browser/servlet can't determine the mimetype: [Is there any default mime type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12539058/is-there-a-default-mime-type)