# Does S3 Bucket Key name require file extension?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

If I am uploading a pdf file in the S3 bucket using SDK. Do I also need to include the suffix “.pdf” in the key.

`PutObjectRequest.builder() .bucket(bucketName) .key(key)`

Is “myName” a valid key in this case or I need to use “myName.pdf” as key.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The key is the full filename, including the path.

Examples:

- `myName.pdf`
- `my-folder/myName.pdf`
- `folder1/folder2/very-important-file.pdf`

You do not *need* to include extension -- the choice of Key is up to you!

You might also want to specify the `Content-Type` so that browsers know how to open the file when it is downloaded. See: [Why does file uploaded to S3 have content type application/octet-stream unless I name the file .html?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30856191/174777)