# PHP File download without "type"

Tags: php, sql, file

Is it possible to download a file saved as MEDIUMBLOB on a MySQL database knowing just its name and content ? Would I require even its type ecc ?

Thanks

Comment: [`application/octect-stream` is suggested  for "unknown \[binary\] files"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1176022/unknown-file-type-mime); if at all possible, I would try to capture (or providing a mapping of) the actual Content/MIME type so that browsers can take [more] appropriate actions..

Answer (score 1):

I'm fairly certain you'd just use the search `WHERE filename LIKE %MEDIUMBLOB%`. Although I'll point out that there are certain security issues with downloading files of unknown types...