# HTTP 1.0 header content-type for unknow file type

Tags: http, http-headers

I am doing an assignment where I have to make a simple HTTP 1.0 server.

I know that htm files has content-type text/html and jpg files has content-type image/jpeg

but what is the content-type if the file type is unknown?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Unknown file type MIME?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1176022/unknown-file-type-mime)

Answer (score 2):

You simply do not send the Content-Type header field.