# JavaScript img.src onerror event - get reason of error

Tags: javascript

There can be different reasons for `<img>` load errors, such as network error response, bad image data...

`error` object received from `onerror` doesn't seems to specify the exact reason.

Is there a way to know if the error is because of a network error, say `HTTP 500` or a network timeout?

**EDIT:**
I'm **not** looking for an alternative way to load a resource, such as AJAX request. I need an answer specifically for `<img>` tag with `onerror` event. The reason for that is that I'm using this method for pixel-tracking and I need a way to retry on upon network errors. I'm also not looking for alternative tracking methods such as JSONP.

Comment: You can see this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9714525/javascript-image-url-verify/9714891#9714891

Comment: This is not answering my question. I edited the question for it to be more specific.

Comment: I just wanted to give you a suggestion, not an answer, because I think is not possible to retrieve the error type from onerror event.

Answer (score 2):

## Edit `16Nov16 2020GMT`

Maybe you are [pixel-tracking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_beacon#Implementation) in emails or other clients limited in Javascript capabilities.

One idea that comes to mind is to use URL query paramters in your `<img>`'s `src` URL.

With regards to network timeouts, I will pose the idea that a user opens an email, loads the email entirely, then disconnects from the internet and somehow this does not give the tracker enough time to load.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setTimeout

I would suggest to use `setTimeout()` inside your `onerror` function.
This will continue attempting to set/load the `<img>`'s `src` URL. You could append the seconds it took until successful load to the URL of your `src` file as a query parameter like `?s=<sec>`

As far as determining status `500` codes on image loads you might want to consider creating a custom `500` error file which would then create -- for example -- a MySQL database entry with all sorts of information you have access to and if you chose to use the query parameters mentioned before then you have slightly more information added to the error.

#### `onerror` for `<img>` gives limited information about the network

The information that is available from `<img>` can be found at
https://www.w3.org/TR/html/semantics-embedded-content.html#htmlimageelement-htmlimageelement

[image: error event img src]

---

## Older answer:

Perhaps a route you would like to try is to use AJAX to load the image data and set the `<img>` src to the base64 of the image data received. I hope this helps.

### Edit `14Nov16 2018GMT`

Alternatively use AJAX to determine if the image loads properly and *then* use the same URL sent to AJAX as the `src` for your `<img>`.  It would of course be redundant but would avoid the issue of long "data" URLs.

### Edit `15Nov16 0832GMT`

Also regarding Network Timeout I found this thread to be useful [JQuery Ajax - How to Detect Network Connection error when making Ajax call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1730692/jquery-ajax-how-to-detect-network-connection-error-when-making-ajax-call)
Apparently you can specify a `timeout` to AJAX much like using `error` except you just provide the miliseconds manually.

### Converting to Base64

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowBase64/Base64_encoding_and_decoding

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowBase64/btoa

  ```
    var encodedData = window.btoa("Hello, world"); // encode a string
  ```

Or if you are concerened about older browsers able to use `btoa()` then you might be interested in Google's https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromiumos/platform/spigots/+/refs/heads/firmware-u-boot-v1/base64_encode.js

### Status Code checks in jQuery's AJAX

[jQuery: How to get the HTTP status code from within the $.ajax.error method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6700822/jquery-how-to-get-the-http-status-code-from-within-the-ajax-error-method)

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: '/path-to-my/image.png',
    data: null,
    success: function(data){
        alert('horray! 200 status code!');
        // convert to base64; add to img.src # btoa(data)
        document.querySelector("#hlogo img").src = "data:;base64,"+ data;
    },
    error:function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){
        switch (xhr.status) {
            case 400:
                 // Take action, referencing xhr.responseText as needed.

            case 404:
                 // Take action, referencing xhr.responseText as needed.

            case 500:
                 // Take action, referencing xhr.responseText as needed.
        }
});
```

#### Notes

- https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2397#section-3

  ```
    dataurl    := "data:" [ mediatype ] [ ";base64" ] "," data
    mediatype  := [ type "/" subtype ] *( ";" parameter )
    data       := *urlchar
    parameter  := attribute "=" value
  ```
- https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2046#section-4.2

> Using of a generic-purpose image viewing application this way
> inherits the security problems of the most dangerous type supported
> by the application.

- https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2397#page-4

> The effect of using long "data" URLs in applications is currently
> unknown; some software packages may exhibit unreasonable behavior
> when confronted with data that exceeds its allocated buffer size.

#### Other References

- [Unknown file type MIME?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1176022/unknown-file-type-mime)
- [Asynchronously load images with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4285042/asychronously-load-images-with-jquery)

Comment: This is not answering my question. I edited the question for it to be more specific.