# Setting image src dynamically using JavaScript failed on iOS

Tags: javascript, ios, image

I have following JavaScript code

```
var aimg = new Image();
aimg.crossOrigin = 'Anonymous';
aimg.onload = function () {
    //execute some code when image loaded
};
aimg.onerror = function () {
    //execute some code when image failed to load
};
aimg.src = someExistedImageUrl;
```

running on Chrome, Firefox on Linux desktop and Android devices, `onload` is correctly triggered. But in iOS, `onerror` is always triggered eventhough image exists and coming from same origin.

Why above code failed to load image in iOS?

**Update**

I add following code as suggested but does not work. The image is relatively small in size, less than 80 KB.

```
aimg.src = null;
```

Comment: What is the error shown?

Comment: No error in console, but `onerror` is always triggered. Open image url manually on browser address bar result in image successfully loaded.

Comment: Can you show what the `onerror` is called with when on iOS?

Comment: Couldn't replicate this

Comment: add `console.log(arguments);` inside the `onerror` function and show us whats printed.

Comment: **its may cause by redirection issue, request may return redirection status(3×× Redirection) 

300 Multiple Choices
301 Moved Permanently
302 Found
303 See Other
304 Not Modified
305 Use Proxy
307 Temporary Redirect

(you can inspect this in Firefox developer tool)

**another possibility is case insensitive / unsupported character in url ,or  invalid /unsupported mime type issue

Comment: @LuisLimas console.log(event) output gives output similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40572712/javascript-img-src-onerror-event-get-reason-of-error

Answer (score 4):

Maybe it's a cache problem. Try this and see whether it's working or not;

```
var aimg = new Image();
aimg.crossOrigin = 'Anonymous';
aimg.onload = function () {
    //execute some code when image loaded
};
aimg.onerror = function () {
    //execute some code when image failed to load
};
aimg.src = null;
aimg.src = someExistedImageUrl;
```

In addition, check you image size.

> JavaScript allocations are also limited to 10 MB. Safari raises an
>   exception if you exceed this limit on the total memory allocation for
>   JavaScript.

For more information, you could check [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2986039/ipad-iphone-browser-crashing-when-loading-images-in-javascript)

Comment: I will try as soon as possible