# ACTION_SEND Intent with unknown content type (*/* vs application/octet-stream)

Tags: android, android-intent, xamarin.android

When sharing an unknown file type with an ACTION_SEND Intent, should `*/*` or `application/octet-stream` be used when setting the content type?

According to **Mozilla**'s [Complete list of MIME types](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/MIME_types/Complete_list_of_MIME_types)

> Two primary MIME types are important for the role of default types:
>
> - text/plain is the default value for textual files. A textual file should be human-readable and must not contain binary data.
> - application/octet-stream is the default value for all other cases. An unknown file type should use this type. Browsers pay a particular care when manipulating these files, attempting to safeguard the user to prevent dangerous behaviors.

Example

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ActionSend);

Uri uri = Uri.FromFile(file);
intent.PutExtra(Intent.ExtraStream, uri);

string fileType = GetMimeTypeByUri(uri);
if (fileType == null)
{
    fileType = "*/*";                      // ?
    fileType = "application/octet-stream"; // ?
    fileType = "application/x-binary"      // ?
}
intent.SetType(fileType);

StartActivity(Intent.CreateChooser(intent, "Send to..."));
```

where

```
private String GetMimeTypeByUri(Uri uri)
{
    if (uri.Scheme.Equals(ContentResolver.SchemeContent))
        return ContentResolver.GetType(uri);
    else
        return Android.Webkit.MimeTypeMap.Singleton.GetMimeTypeFromExtension(
            Android.Webkit.MimeTypeMap.GetFileExtensionFromUrl(uri.Path).ToLower()
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: it seems yes by referring this article http://androidsbs.blogspot.com.tr/2014/01/intent-settypestring-type-how-to-set.html

Comment: You want open an unknown file using a suitable apps?

Comment: @YorkShen-MSFT ACTION_GET_CONTENT is for "opening".

Comment: You could read the [official documents](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_SEND)  : Use `*/*` if the MIME type is unknown.

Comment: @YorkShen-MSFT ..."this will only allow senders that can handle generic data streams"... I'm not sure exactly what that is, but I could always read the source.

Answer (score 2):

> fileType = "* / *";

If you use a mime type of "* / *" when you can't determine it from the system(it is null) it fires the appropriate select application dialog.

> fileType = "application/octet-stream";

Typically, it will be an application or a document that must be opened in an application, such as a spreadsheet or word processor.
[The "octet-stream" subtype is used to indicate that a body contains arbitrary binary data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1176022/unknown-file-type-mime?noredirect=1&lq=1)

> fileType = "application/x-binary"

it's just a non-standard way of restating "octet-stream".

Check the links for details [MIME types](https://github.com/anwarjaved/mimetype/blob/master/mimetypes.xml) , [MIME Utils](http://androidxref.com/4.4.4_r1/xref/libcore/luni/src/main/java/libcore/net/MimeUtils.java)

Hope this may hep you.